# Render being cropped?

Tags: rendering

I am trying out some of the Freestyle line setups from here: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/18717

When I render using these .blend files, I am getting a cropped render. How can the render be edited to show the full view in a different size?

[image: cropped render]
Preview of cropped render

Comment: Do you have a rectangular red dotted line in the viewport when looking through the camera? That would indicate you had enabled render-regions, and you would need to go into camera view, and press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`B`

Comment: I checked and unfortunately no, I didn't see a red dotted line in the viewport when looking through the camera. I am rendering with BI.

Comment: Could you upload your specific .blend to [**pasteall.org/blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) and post the link here?

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33929

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background image is limiting the size of your render. If you look closely, you will notice that the render image that is not black is exactly the same size and color of the texture. The rest of the camera view is filled with the default black, or if you check *Film > Transparent* with a transparent alpha value.

You will either need to change the size of your image, or do some work in your compositor.

One way to do this is to add a *Scale* node after your image texture like this:

[image]

(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Distort > Scale*)

The result now looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I got the files off Blender Swap so I have no ideas what was causing it. : )

Comment: No problem, having the .blend certainly helped me find it quicker :)